# MySQL Git Bash winpty mysqldump stdout is not a tty and stdin is not a tty

Tags: mysql, git-bash

Please help with MySQL Git Bash winpty mysqldump. "winpty mysqldump" is not working in Git Bash. Here the details of the error:

**Git Bash**

```
$ winpty mysqldump -u root -p employeedb > "E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\MySQL-Queries\mysqldump\SQL-dump\employeedb_backup.sql"
stdout is not a tty

$ winpty mysql -u root -p employeedb < "E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\MySQL-Queries\mysqldump\SQL-dump\employeedb_backup.sql"
stdin is not a tty
```

However Git CMD works fine:

**Git CMD**

```
C:\Users\Aspire>mysqldump -u root -p employeedb > "E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\MySQL-Queries\mysqldump\SQL-dump\employeedb_backup.sql"
Enter password: ****************

C:\Users\Aspire>mysql -u root -p employeedb < "E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\MySQL-Queries\mysqldump\SQL-dump\employeedb_backup.sql"
Enter password: ****************
```

**Git Bash works with winpty mysqldump and winpty mysql without ">" and "<"**

```
$ winpty mysqldump -u root -p employeedb

Enter password: ****************
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.14, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: employeedb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.7.14-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `employee`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employee`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Salary` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `employee`
--

LOCK TABLES `employee` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `employee` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `employee` VALUES (1,'A',10000.00),(2,'B',8000.00),(3,'C',8000.00),(4,'D',6000.00),(5,'E',6000.00),(6,'F',6000.00),(7,'G',5000.00),(8,'H',5000.00),(9,'I',5000.00),(10,'
J',5000.00),(11,'K',4000.00),(12,'L',4000.00),(13,'M',3000.00),(14,'N',3000.00),(15,'O',1000.00),(16,'P',14000.00),(17,'Q',14000.00),(18,'R',12000.00),(19,'S',12000.00),(20,'T',160
00.00),(21,'U',16000.00),(22,'V',16000.00),(23,'W',14000.00),(24,'X',12000.00),(25,'Y',12000.00),(26,'Z',10000.00);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `employee` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2016-11-18 20:43:00
```

Please help with winpty mysqldump/winpty mysql and stdout/stdin tty?

**Git Bash "mysqldump" without winpty does not work:**

The command $ mysqldump -u root -p employeedb > "E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\MySQL-Queries\mysqldump\SQL-dump\employeedb_backup.sql" just freezes.

Please refer to the "employeedb_backup.sql" script size 0 KB.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is actually from `winpty` because you are trying to redirect output to a file and it expects a terminal for interactive use.

Normally, native Git bash commands like `git`, `ssh` and all output redirection like `node --version | clip` should work without `winpty`.

These `mysql` commands are different in that they need interactive input (for password entry) before redirecting their output. In order to correctly work we need to make them run through `winpty` without using output redirection.

```
$ winpty mysqldump -u USER -p DB_NAME -r OUTPUT.sql
Enter password: ******
```

> --result-file=file_name, -r file_name
>   Direct output to a given file. This option should be used on Windows to prevent newline "\n" characters from being converted to "\r\n" carriage return/newline sequences. The result file is created and its previous contents overwritten, even if an error occurs while generating the dump.

[image: mysqldump screenshot]

```
$ winpty mysql -u USER -p DB_NAME
Enter password: ******

mysql> source INPUT.sql
```

[image: mysql screenshot]

Comment: Git Bash "mysqldump" without winpty does not work:

The command $ mysqldump -u root -p employeedb > "E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\MySQL-Queries\mysqldump\SQL-dump\employeedb_backup.sql" just freezes.

Please refer to the "employeedb_backup.sql" script size 0 KB.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize that if you have a password it will need an interactive tty to insert credentials. Fixed my answer.

Comment: I'd like to be able to do something like `mysql -u XX -p YY < INPUT.sql` with the git bash shell, but it's not working, even using winpty (I can start up mysql by itself fine with winpty). Is it not possible to invoke mysql with the input redirection on one command? I.e. do I have to get into mysql and then issue the source command always?

Comment: Because of the limitations imposed by `winpty` I did not find a way to do imports in a single command line. Your best option might be the source command (shown at the bottom of my answer).

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar problem with git bash on Windows 10 (using the php command).

I fixed it by appending the extension (.exe) to php.

```
julien@SED-221-10 MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs
$ php -v > php
stdout is not a tty

julien@SED-221-10 MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs
$ php.exe -v > php
```

EDIT:

You can also add an alias if you don't want to append .exe to all your commands like so :

```
$ printf "\nalias mysql='mysql.exe'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: That `php.exe` trick was what I needed to get a complicated command I lost an hour trying to figure out where it was going wrong. Those `tty` errors on Windows really suck. Tried some eval stuff and saw the word winpty, and then found this thread. Just wish this wasn't a Windows specific fix so I can have the same command work on other Operating systems.

Comment: @Ultimater, well I never came across this problem in Linux, don't think it happens in Mac Os either. Creating the alias, you can use the standard command (without the .exe) in Windows, so your command is the same for all OS.

Comment: Thats working fine. I yous would like to add any global definition (like PATHEXT in windows) what translates adds the .exe to all commands which are builin cygwin command.

Comment: This exactly solved it for me on Windows 7 with git bash.  Running `type pip` shows that it's running pip as an alias for `winpty pip`.  Explicitly calling pip avoids this winpty problem.

Comment: Does anybody know why this works..... ? Or maybe I just shouldn't think too hard about it, heh...

Comment: I think it works because the directory where the binary lies is part of your path. But the filename is indeed xyz.exe thus you have to refer to that name. In Linux, most file in /bin and similar directory do not have an extension, but if they did, you would have to specify it in your commands

Comment: My guess but that is only a guess, is when you don't specify the actual file name, the process is handled outside the tty aka by Windows. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Unbelievable, but this really works, thanks