# msys / mingw command line requires or rejects exe extension based on whether stdout is redirected with ConEmu console

Tags: console, mingw, stdout, tty, msys

The underlying cause of this problem is described elsewhere, with partial workarounds provided.

For example: [stdout is not a tty and stdin is not a tty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680812/mysql-git-bash-winpty-mysqldump-stdout-is-not-a-tty-and-stdin-is-not-a-tty)

An example of a command line I'm having problems with in MSYS2 or MINGW64 environments is this:

```
# psql -c '\d' | grep public
stdout is not a tty
```

Here's the output, if issued without piping to `grep`:

```
# psql -c '\d'
               List of relations
 Schema |      Name      |   Type   |  Owner
--------+----------------+----------+----------
 public | tagname        | table    | postgres
 public | tagname_id_seq | sequence | postgres
(2 rows)
```

In order to redirect stdout, it's apparently necessary to edit the command line, changing `psql` to `psql.exe`.   This modification does the trick:

```
# psql.exe -c '\d' | grep public
 public | tagname        | table    | postgres
 public | tagname_id_seq | sequence | postgres
```

This version works, whether or not `stdout` is redirected:

```
# psql.exe -c '\d'
               List of relations
 Schema |      Name      |   Type   |  Owner
--------+----------------+----------+----------
 public | tagname        | table    | postgres
 public | tagname_id_seq | sequence | postgres
(2 rows)
```

Note that the problem only exists for some programs.  For example, `/usr/bin/find` is indifferent to whether the `.exe` extension is specified.  Also, the `cygwin` version of `psql.exe` does not suffer from this limitation.

The workaround of appending `.exe` could be hidden with an alias if you could always call `psql` as `psql.exe`, but there are problems with interactive sessions when called with the extension. (in `ConEmu` terminal under `MSYS_NT-10.0-19042`, for example)

So my question is this: is it possible to create a wrapper program (for example, in `golang` or `C`, or a shell script) to hide this problem?  The goal would be to support optionally redirectable command lines without requiring the `.exe` extension.

Assuming the wrapper is named "fixtty", it would spawn a command line that could be redirected or not.   In other words, neither of these command lines would fail with an error message:

```
# fixtty psql -c '\d'
# fixtty psql -c '\d' | grep public
```

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper script (call it `fixtty`) that hides the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  # stdout is a terminal
  "$@"
else
  # stdout is a file or pipe
  PROG=$1 ; shift
  set -- "$PROG.exe" "$@" # append .exe suffix
  "$@"
fi
```

Usage:

```
$ fixtty psql -c '\d'                 # unfiltered `stdout`
$ fixtty psql -c '\d' | grep public   # filtered
$ fixtty psql                         # launch interactive session
```